# Can apply storage class specifiers to formal arguments

Tags: c++, c

Formal arguments stored in which memory section ?
Can i apply storage class specifiers to Formal arguments like auto,static.

if applying storage class specifiers to formal arguments Gcc compiler only giving error.Other compilers allowing tell me which concept is good.

Comment: You're probably not supposed to care where they are, but they live on the stack (which I think matches the old meaning of the "auto" keyword). You cannot choose to have them somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The only storage class specifier you can apply to function parameters is `register` (and the old meaning of `auto`). All the other ones are explicitly prohibited in this context by section `[dcl.stc]` in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

No. we can not specify storage class to formal arguments.
consider this example,

```
void display(static int a) //ERROR
{
  cout<<a++;
}
main()
{
 display(2);
 display(1);
}
```

here the formal argument cant be static because the static variable is declared once then used so on subsequent calls to functions variable a cant get declared and get the value. its a reason i thought apart from the fact that formal arguments are allocated on stack.